# How to document JSON Merge Patch endpoints in OpenAPI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I have implemented a REST API which is documented via OpenAPI. In detail, the specification is generated from Java source code using springdoc-openapi.

However, I have the need for accepting patches. So, I

```yaml
  /customers/{id}:
    patch:
      tags:
        - Customers
      summary: Updates an existing user
      description: Updates an existing user
      operationId: partialUpdateMergePatchCustomer
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: The numeric ID of the customer
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/merge-patch+json:
            schema:
              type: object
        required: true
```

I have read through the OpenAPI specification/documentation but did not find any information regarding JSON Merge Patch, JSON Patch or the like.

I am experiencing the following issues I'd like to overcome:

1. There is no clue information of which type of resource is to be patched here. The rest of the API, esp. in SwaggerUI, is well documented and has schema references everywhere. How can I specify the resources schema that actually is to be patched?
2. Apart from the pure schema reference, in my API, some resources have read-only fields or there may be other restrictions that apply to certain fields that I'd like to document. Is there a better way as doing it in natural language as part of the original schema?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as your issue #1. That is, providing more info to swagger on the JsonPatch RequestBody parameter than the default generated by springdoc-openapi. I'm posting my solution here for others who may run into the same issue.

My solution was to add the following annotation to the RestController patch method:

```java
@PatchMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = "application/json-patch+json")
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = JsonPatchSchema.class))))
    public void patch(@PathVariable @Min(0) long id, @RequestBody JsonPatch patch) {
```

Where JsonPatchSchema contains the requested format:

```java
public class JsonPatchSchema {
    @NotBlank
    public Op op;

    public enum Op {
        replace, add, remove, copy, move, test
    }

    @NotBlank
    @Schema(example = "/name")
    public String path;

    @NotBlank
    public String value;
}
```

Using the `@Schema` annotation you could provide more detail on what is allowed, see the [Schema javadoc](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0-RC3/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html). For example the pattern parameter allows you to define a regular expression. I haven't found a way to generate the allowed content unfortunately.